# CameraRoll Square Display and Circular Mask - UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, mask

I am experimenting on Camera roll using UIImagePickerController. I have achieved presenting camera view with custom buttons (and to achieve that, I used another ViewController with an xib (CustomOverlayVC.swift)). So I have:

- MainViewController.swift (+ Storyboard)
- CustomOverlayViewController.swift
- CustomOverlayView.swift (UIView)

`full code below`

---

After creating NavBar programatically on CustomOverlayVC, this is what it looks like so far (and also what I want to achieve on the right)

[image] [image]

---

So my problems are:

1) How can I narrow down the imagepicker's view like the second image (displaying well as taking the picture in square format?)

I tried `picker.view.frame.height -= 40` but apparently it's only get property.

2) How can I have a mask over the image that will show a circular mask? *(This is explained for objective-c [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/uiimagepickercontroller-editing-view-circle-overlay-resolved.1689199/) but I don't know any obj-c and couldn't convert it successfully to Swift)*

[image]

3) I tried to give it a custom background color with `picker.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` however, it doesn't work at all. To clear, in second example it has grayish background color.

4) *Also, the navbar that I have created looks much wider even though I used,* (I know this is a different issue but having it solved would be highly appreciated)

```
UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
```

---

**So to wrap up, I want to narrow the height of its view until it gets square (as well as taking photo of the square) *(2nd picture)*, and also, at the same time, have a circular mask and greyed outside the circle *(the last picture)***

I have created a [sample project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxWHl6OLoWW6VUFVc1dhS0NNRzA), also full code is below..

---

ViewController.swift

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var picker = UIImagePickerController()


@IBAction func shootCamera(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.availableCaptureModesForCameraDevice(.Rear) != nil {
        picker = UIImagePickerController() //make a clean controller
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker.cameraDevice = .Front
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        picker.showsCameraControls = false

        picker.delegate = self

        let customViewController = CameraCustomOverlayViewController(nibName:"CameraCustomOverlayViewController",bundle: nil)
        let customView:CameraCustomOverlayView = customViewController.view as! CameraCustomOverlayView
        customView.frame = self.picker.view.frame

        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
        presentViewController(picker,animated: true,completion: {
            self.picker.cameraOverlayView = customView
        })

    } else { //no camera found -- alert the user.
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(
            title: "No Camera",
            message: "Sorry, this device has no camera",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style:.Default,
            handler: nil)
        alertVC.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(
            alertVC,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //2
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, self,nil, nil)
}

//What to do if the image picker cancels.
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

CustomOverlayVC.swift (for NavBar)

```
class CameraCustomOverlayViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44))
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "CAMERAROLL"
    let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:   UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CameraCustomOverlayViewController.btn_clicked(_:)))
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**:

For understanding the height, I tried adding coloured border, it covers the whole view not the ImagePicker's view to me... I couldn't figure out any way to solve it..

```
  picker.view.layer.borderWidth = 1
  picker.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved from UIImagePickerController to AVFoundation approach to accomplish more customised camera roll